# How to create folders in django admin?

Tags: python, django

Currently, I want to create a folder whenever I try to add a new tag in Django admin. But I don't know how to realize this function. my model.py code is as below:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    Tag_name = models.CharField('Tag Name', max_length=10, default='NA')
    Description = models.TextField('Tag Description', max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tags'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Tag_name
```

The function I want is, for example, if I create a tag named "test", the system will automatically create a folder named "test" in a specific place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/), in your `model.py`

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


def callback(*args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    # Do after save

post_save.connect(callback, sender=Tags)
```

Comment: Hi Rin, thank you for your help. I successfully realized this function with this code! There is still a question that I just used time to name the folders I created. But I want to use "Tag name" for the folder name. How can I pass the tag name to the post_save function?

Comment: the `instance` is your added tag. Just use `instance.Tag_name`.